# Google App Engine Calendar

Tags: google-app-engine, google-calendar-api

Does anyone have a link or can provide the code for a Java Google App Engine project which simply interacts with Google Calendar. Say get an event from your calendar.

The Google Sample calendar-appengine-sample does not compile once checkout out from HG and I have tried searching for tutorials and creating my own with only small bits of luck in places.

I have already set up an API Access project to get the client-secrets.json.

Comment: I think after 4 years you should know that your signature is in the bottom right.. so there is no need for extra signatures and cheers on SO..

Comment: I don't think politeness is such a bad thing and certainly not worth commenting on. Did it really negatively impact the post .... no I don't think SO. Thanks for your helpful response though!

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021/142717

Comment: Well done, I can see many people agree with you. However the world is a big place so not everyone will agree. Editing posts you are not even supplying any useful addition to is a bit poor in my book.

Comment: James.. I think the edits that are clearly removing greetings it's pretty self explained so what's the point of writing that? and the second most voted [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/142717) is by mister Jeff.. so I think his opinion matters.. and again we are all here to help and get helped so there is no need for the usual formalities.. that is assumed :)

Comment: Well as requested I have stopped, so I do listen, but a polite suggestion that I don't add thank etc would have been a lot easier. I appreciate Jeff's opinion matters but it is an opinion and in the same way they script the removal of Hi's they could script the removal of Thanks + USER_ID at the end. Little help was provided on this question which essentially was asking for some links or suggestions, which other would/could have found useful.

Answer (score 1):

So as much as some think this is a poor question it demonstrates that there is not much out there in terms of help with the combination of Java, App Engine and OAuth. I have an ex Google employee at my company and he did agree that it is not as straightforward as it should be.

Based on the reply to my post on the Google Group I decided to use Python where the OAuth2Decorator makes the task trivial.

This was a very useful tutorial: https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/python/getting_started_with_tasks_api

If you HAVE to use Java these I apologise for this not really helping you, but if you are willing to give Python a go then I recommend the above link and using PyDev with Eclipse.